# Adding Encoding in PoolProperties class

Tags: java, mysql

I am using library `tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar` for connection pooling in my project. The problem which I faced is I am unable to set connection properties `useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;` from java source.

I have tried adding the connection properties of `PooledProperties` class but it didnt work

```
public static DataSource getEsmgDataSource(){

     if(dataSourceEsmg == null){
            DataSource eds = new DataSource();
            PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
            String dburl = ConfigurationManager.getDBProperties("smsc.url");
            String username = ConfigurationManager.getDBProperties("smsc.user");
            String password = ConfigurationManager.getDBProperties("smsc.password");
            try {
                DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(Helper.GetException(e));
            }
            p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            p.setUrl(dburl);
            p.setUsername(username);
            p.setPassword(password);
            p.setMaxActive(2000);
            p.setValidationQuery("select 1");
            p.setValidationInterval(5000);
            p.setMinIdle(Integer.parseInt(ConfigurationManager.getDBProperties("db.connection.esmg.min.idle")));
            p.setMaxWait(Integer.parseInt(ConfigurationManager.getDBProperties("db.connection.esmg.max.wait")));//3000);     
            p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
            p.setConnectionProperties("useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;");
            p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(Integer.parseInt(ConfigurationManager.getDBProperties("db.connection.esmg.abandoned.timeout")));//5);

            eds.setPoolProperties(p);

            dataSourceEsmg = eds;
        }
     return dataSourceEsmg;
}
```

How can I set the encoding from java source?

Comment: What do you mean by it not working? Is it failing, or the encoding is still incorrect?

Comment: getting below exception 
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x89' for column 'message' at row 1
if i try it without connection pooling and set encoding in url everything is working fine then, but i need to implement it via connection pooling